# Mongoose partial update of an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple user model:

```
{
  _id: "59d72070d9d03b28934b972b"
  firstName: "first"
  lastName: "last"
  email: "first.last@gmail.com"
  subscriptions: {
    newsletter: true,
    blog: true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do partial updates on the `subscriptions` object. I'm passing the `id` of the user and a `payload` object that can have either one or both properties of the object. Let's say I only want to update `newsletter` and set it to `false`. I'll send:

```
{ id: "59d72070d9d03b28934b972b", payload: { newsletter: false } }
```

And then:

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  args.id,
  { $set: { subscriptions: args.payload } },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
);
```

This will return:

```
subscriptions: {
  newsletter: false
}
```

Is there a way to only modify the `newsletter` property when I only pass `newsletter` in the payload object without deleting the other properties? I know I only have two properties in this example, but in time, the object will keep expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
const user = await User.findById(args.id);

// merge subscriptions
user.subscriptions = Object.assign({}, user.subscriptions, args.payload);

return user.save();
```

Comment: this will work but will perform 2 requests : 1 `users.findOne` and 1 `users.update` vs only 1 `users.findAndModify` initially

Answer (score 5):

To update only the nested field, use `{ "subscriptions.newsletter": false }` :

```
const user = (await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    args.id, {
        $set: {
            "subscriptions.newsletter": args.payload
        }
    }, {
        new: true
    }
));
```

If your input can have missing fields, you can build a dynamic query in `$set` with only the fields you have specified in your input :

```
async function save(id, query) {
    const user = (await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id, {
            $set: query
        }, {
            new: true
        }
    ));
    console.log(user);
}

var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59d91f1a06ecf429c8aae221");
var input = {
    newsletter: false,
    blog: false
};

var query = {};
for (var key in input) {
    query["subscriptions." + key] = input[key];
}

save(id, query);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to update my object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To partial update parent doc and/or subDoc, formulate payload as:

```
const args = { id: "59d72070d9d03b28934b972b", payload: { firstName: "John", subscriptions.newsletter: false } }

await User.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id, args.payload);
```